# I am creating a Codeigniter library, how do i test the code?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a library in codeigniter for a roulette system.

I am looking to make the code very efficient and hack-proof.

1. Are there any tools that i can use to test the code, like functional testing etc?
2. Is the code efficient? If not how to test / increase efficiency?

this is the code

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
* Name:  Prad Roulette
*
* Version: 0.1
*
* Author: Pradyummna Reddy
*         prad@hireprad.co.uk
*         
*
* Location: https://github.com/pradyummna/prad_roulette
*
* Created:  21/10/2014
*
* Description:  The library can be used for roulette system developers
*
* Requirements: PHP5 or above
*
*/

class Prad_roulette
{

    /**
     *
     * Function to find if the number is a valid roulette number
     *
     * @param  integer  $number The number to which has to be checked
     *
     * @return boolean 
     *
     * Anchor: 1num
     */
     function isValidRouletteNumber($number)
    {
        if(ctype_digit($number) && $number < 37 && $number >= 0 ){return true;}else{return false;}
    }


    /**
     * Function to finds the number's color` in a roulette table
     *
     * @param  integer  $number The number to which the colour is to be determined
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * Anchor : 2color
     */
    function findColour($number)
    {

        // checking the input numbers
        if(!($this->isValidRouletteNumber($number))){return 'InValidInput';}

        $wheel = array('0','32','15','19','4','21','2','25','17','34','6','27','13','36','11','30','8','23','10','5','24','16','33','1','20','14','31','9','22','18','29','7','28','12','35','3','26');

        $numberInArray = array_keys($wheel, $number);

        if(isset($numberInArray[0]))
        {
            if($numberInArray[0] == '0')
            {$blackRred='ZERO';}
            else{
                    if($numberInArray[0] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        //its black!!!
                        $blackRred='Black';
                    }
                    else{ $blackRred = 'Red'; }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            $blackRred = 'OUT';
        }

    return $blackRred;  
    }

    /**
     * Function to finds the number's neighbours left to them
     *
     * @param  integer  $number The number to which the left neighbours is to be determined
     * @param  integer  $howManyNeighbours The total neighbours to be found
     * @return array
     *
     * Anchor: neiLside
     */
    function neighboursLeft($number,$howManyNeighbours)
    {   
        // checking the input numbers
        if(!($this->isValidRouletteNumber($number)) || !($this->isValidRouletteNumber($howManyNeighbours))){return array('InValidInput');}

        $x = $howManyNeighbours;
        $wheel = array('0','32','15','19','4','21','2','25','17','34','6','27','13','36','11','30','8','23','10','5','24','16','33','1','20','14','31','9','22','18','29','7','28','12','35','3','26');

        $numberInArray = array_keys($wheel, $number);

        $neighboursLeft = null;
        if(isset($numberInArray[0]))
        {
            $currentNumber = $numberInArray[0];

            //finding the end of the array
            $startValueInArray = reset($wheel);
            //$endArrayKey = key($wheel);               
            //reset($wheel);

            //moving to the current position value position in the array
            while (key($wheel) !== $numberInArray[0]) next($wheel);

            $neighboursLeft[0] = 'In';
            for($i=0;$i<$x;$i++)
            {
                if(current($wheel) != $startValueInArray)
                {
                    //echo next($wheel);echo '::'.$i; echo '<br/>';
                    $neighboursLeft[$i+1] =  prev($wheel);
                }
                else
                {
                    end($wheel);
                    //echo current($wheel);echo '::'.$i;echo '<br/>';
                    $neighboursLeft[$i+1] =  current($wheel);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $neighboursLeft = array('OUT');
        }
        //$neighboursLeft[0] can be OUT or In 
        return $neighboursLeft;

    }

    /**
     * Function to finds the number's neighbours right to them
     *
     * @param  integer  $number The number to which the right neighbours is to be determined
     * @param  integer  $howManyNeighbours The total neighbours to be found
     * @return array
     *
     * Anchor: neirside
     */
    function neighboursRight($number,$howManyNeighbours)
    {

        // checking the input numbers
        if(!($this->isValidRouletteNumber($number)) || !($this->isValidRouletteNumber($howManyNeighbours))){return array('InValidInput');}


        $x = $howManyNeighbours;
        $wheel = array('0','32','15','19','4','21','2','25','17','34','6','27','13','36','11','30','8','23','10','5','24','16','33','1','20','14','31','9','22','18','29','7','28','12','35','3','26');

        $numberInArray = array_keys($wheel, $number);

        $neighboursRight = null;
        if(isset($numberInArray[0]))
        {
            $currentNumber = $numberInArray[0];

            //finding the end of the array
            $endValueInArray = end($wheel);
            //$endArrayKey = key($wheel);               
            reset($wheel);

            //moving to the current position value position in the array
            while (key($wheel) !== $numberInArray[0]) next($wheel);

            $neighboursRight[0] = 'In';
            for($i=0;$i<$x;$i++)
            {
                if(current($wheel) != $endValueInArray)
                {
                    //echo next($wheel);echo '::'.$i; echo '<br/>';
                    $neighboursRight[$i+1] =  next($wheel);
                }
                else
                {
                    reset($wheel);
                    //echo current($wheel);echo '::'.$i;echo '<br/>';
                    $neighboursRight[$i+1] =  current($wheel);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $neighboursRight = array('OUT');
        }

        // $neighboursRight[0] can be OUT or In
        return $neighboursRight;

    }

    /**
     * Function to finds the number's neighbours right to them
     *
     * @param  array  $numbers The number to which the right neighbours is to be determined
     * @param  array  $moneyOnNumbers The total neighbours to be found
     * @param  integer $winningNumber The winning number
     * @return array payoutAmount, Profit, Invested amount
     *
     * Anchor: xPayoutProfit
     */
    function payoutProfit($numbers,$moneyOnNumbers,$winningNumber)
    {
        // checking the input numbers
        if(!($this->isValidRouletteNumber($number)) || !($this->isValidRouletteNumber($winningNumber))){return array('InValidInput');}

        //find the payout

            if(in_array($winningNumber,$numbers))
            {
                $amountOnNumber = $moneyOnNumbers[array_search($winningNumber)];
                $payoutAmount = $amountOnNumber * 36;
            }
            else
            {
                $payoutAmount = 0;
            }           
            $totalInvested = 0;

            // find the amount invested on it
            foreach($moneyOnNumbers as $money)
            {
                $totalInvested = $totalInvested + $money;
            }           

            //calculate profit
            $profit = $payoutAmount - $totalInvested;

            //return
            return array($payoutAmount,$totalInvested,$profit);
    }


    /**
     * Function to finds the number's neighbour right to it
     *
     * @param  integer  $number The number to which the right xth neighbour is to be determined
     * @param  integer  $distanceToXthNumber Distance to the xth neighbour
     *
     * @return integer number in the xth position
     *
     * Anchor: XthNeiRside
     */
    function findXthNumberOnRight($number,$distanceToXthNumber)
    {
        // checking the input numbers
        if(!($this->isValidRouletteNumber($number)) || !($this->isValidRouletteNumber($distanceToXthNumber))){return array('InValidInput');}
        if($distanceToXthNumber != '0')
        {
            $xthNumber = $this->neighboursRight($number,$distanceToXthNumber);
            $xthNumber = $xthNumber[$distanceToXthNumber];
        }
        else
        {
            return $number;
        }

        //find the payout
        return $xthNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Function to finds the number's xth neighbour left to it
     *
     * @param  integer  $number The number to which the left xth neighbour is to be determined
     * @param  integer  $distanceToXthNumber Distance to the xth neighbour
     *
     * @return integer number in the xth position
     *
     * Anchor: XthNeiLside
     */
    function findXthNumberOnLeft($number,$distanceToXthNumber)
    {
        // checking the input numbers
        if(!($this->isValidRouletteNumber($number)) || !($this->isValidRouletteNumber($distanceToXthNumber))){return array('InValidInput');}
        if($distanceToXthNumber != '0')
        {
            $xthNumber = $this->neighboursLeft($number,$distanceToXthNumber);
            $xthNumber = $xthNumber[$distanceToXthNumber];
        }
        else
        {
            return $number;
        }

        //find the payout
        return $xthNumber;
    }
}





//1000861505
```

Function in the library 
1.  Function to check if the number is a valid number or not (input: number | output: true/false) [anchor: 1num]

2. Function to return a colour based on the given number (input: number | output: colour) [anchor: 2color]
3. Function to find neighbours on to the right of a given number (input: number, number of neighbours | output: array of numbers) [anchor: neirside]
4. Function to find neighbours on to the left of a given number (input: number, number of neighbours | output: array of numbers) [anchor: neiLside]
5. Function to return profit n payoutAmount for the game (input: array(invested numbers), array(amount invested ), winning number | output: array( amountReceivedAtTheEnd, profit, lossAmount, investedAmount)) [anchor: xPayoutProfit]
6. Function to find xth neighbour on the right (input: number, distanceToXthNumber | output: number) [anchor: XthNeiRside]
7. Function to find xth neighbour on the left (input: number, distanceToXthNumber | output: number) [anchor: XthNeiLside]
8. Function to find the neighbour distance right (clock wise) (input: number1, number2 | output: total numbers inbetween)
9. Function to find the neighbour distance left (Anti clock wise) (input: number1, number2 | output: total numbers inbetween)
10. Function to know which dozen the number belongs to (input: number | output: dozen's number or 0)
11. Function to see if the number is even or odd (input: number | output: even r odd r 0)
12. Function to to find Low1to18OrHigh19to36 (input: winning Number | output: low or high or 0)
13. Function to find the column number 1st 2nd or 3rd (input: winning number | output: column number or 0)
14. Function to return finals(1,11,21,31,2,22,32..) for the number given (input: winning number | output: finals number)
15. Function to return sector of the wheel (input: winning number | output: sector name[zero game, neighbours of zero..])

Comment: include library and call library function

Comment: There is nothing in this code that ties it to codeignitor - you can test it however you normally test php code. As far as efficiency there are certainly some improvements that can be made, but that sort of question should probably be on codereview, not stackoverflow

Comment: Wrong. The first line does.

Answer (score 5):

You should do the following things to use it as a library
**1. Place your library file inside application/third_party folder.**

[image]

**2.Create another file inside application/libraries folder and extend the class like below.**

[image]

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
 require_once APPPATH."/third_party/Prad_roulette.php"; 

class Roulette extends Prad_roulette { 

}
```

Note: If you need to use a constructor in your class make sure you extend the parent constructor:

```
class Roulette extends Prad_roulette {
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

**3.Finally load your library.**

```
$this->load->library('roulette');
```

To check if the library is loaded or not, you can perform method_exits function like below

```
if(method_exists($this->roulette,'isValidRouletteNumber')){ /* isValidRouletteNumber is the method of Prad_roulette class. */
        echo "Library is loaded successfully";
}else{
        echo "Couldn't load the library";
}
```

Comment: I like your approach of solving the problem.